# Slow down kafka connector JDBC source - control throughput

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to control the throughtput of a JDBC source kafka connector.

I have a lot of data stored in a PostgreSQL table and I wand to ingest it into a Kafka topic. However I would like to **avoid a huge "peak"** in the ingestion.

My config looks like:

```json
{
    "name": "my-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topic.prefix": "my-topic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "password",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "time",
        "poll.interval.ms": "10000",
        "batch.max.rows": "100",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM my-table",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

I guess I would need to play with these parameters:

- `poll.interval.ms`
- `batch.max.rows`

I don't understand how they impact the throughput. With these values it goes really fast.

How can I configure it properly to slow it down?

Edit: the idea looks like [KIP-731](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-731%3A+Record+Rate+Limiting+for+Kafka+Connect) and the propose to limit record rate.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to pass a custom `query` to the connector configuration to `LIMIT` the number of messages returned by query:

```json
{
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db",
  "connection.user": "<user>",
  "connection.password": "<password>",
  "topic.prefix": "my-topic",
  "mode": "timestamp",
  "timestamp.column.name": "time",
  "query": " SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE \"time\" > ? AND \"time\" < ? ORDER BY \"time\" ASC ) t LIMIT 500 -- ",
  "batch.max.rows": "500",
  "poll.interval.ms": "1000",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}
```

The import part is the `query` parameter with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE \"time\" > ? AND \"time\" < ? ORDER BY \"time\" ASC ) t LIMIT 500 --
```

*Note the `--` at the end of the query to comment what the connector append to the query and control it yourself.*

The other important parameter is `poll.interval.ms` set to `"1000"`.

Thus, here I process around 500 msg/s. You can increase the number in the SQL query after `LIMIT` to increase the throughput.

Note: I just see `query.suffix` argument to the connector which may help to pass a `LIMIT` to the SQL query. I didn't try it. Check the [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#connector).

Answer (score -1):

You currently have `batch.max.rows=100` which is the default

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#connector

Once 100 rows are included in the batch, the connector will send the batch to the Kafka topic. If you want to increase throughput you should try increasing this value.

Comment: My objective is to decrease the throughout. I want to send small batch to Kafka and not at a high speed rate.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to avoid overwhelming downstream systems? You mentioned the data is ingested into the Kafka topic at a fast rate, why are you trying to prevent this happening? In summary, you are trying to control two measures - throughput and latency. If latency is high the data will take longer to reach the Kafka Topic. To increase the latency, in Kafka producers you can play with linger.ms, however, I'm not sure the JDBC connector has this configuration. The two configurations in your post won't affect latency.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid overwhelming downstream systems. I found a solution based on "query" field, I will post the solution soon :)